# How to store values generated randomly within a while loop in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, raster

In the example below we create a landscape with cell values 1 and 2. Then we want to create patches with the ID 3, with a size between 1 and 10 cells and repeat this until there are 50 cells with the patch ID.

How would also store the randomised patch size from each iteration of the loop so I end up with a list of the patch sizes selected.

```
library(landscapeR)
library(raster)

Test_landscape <- raster(nrows=50, ncols=50, vals=1) # create raster
Test_landscape[Test_landscape[] == 1] <- # will have 20% unsuitable for patch
  sample(
    c(1,2),
    size = length(Test_landscape[Test_landscape[] ==
                                       1]),
    replace  = T,
    prob = c(0.7, 0.2)
  )

while (length(Test_landscape[Test_landscape[] == 3]) < 50) { # repeat patch making until we have 50 cells
  
  size.clusters <- as.numeric(sample(1:10, 1)) # These are the values that I would like to store?
  Test_landscape <-
    makePatch(
      Test_landscape,
      size = size.clusters,
      bgr = 1, # sutiable cells to make a patch
      edge = FALSE,
      rast = TRUE,
      val = 3 # values given to new patch 
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a set.seed, and also suggest your initial `sample` isn't having the desired effect, that you'll see if you plot it. When things don't work when I try to combine them, I break them back apart to smaller, working pieces:

```
library(landscapeR)
library(raster)
set.seed(516)
tst_ls <- raster(nrows = 50, ncols = 50,vals = 1)
ncell(tst_ls)
[1] 2500
tst_12 <- sample(c(1,2), size = ncell(tst_ls), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.2))
tst_ls <- setValues(tst_ls, tst_12)
ncell(tst_ls) * 0.7

[1] 1750
```

```
length(which(values(tst_ls) == 1))

[1] 1976
```

```
length(which(values(tst_ls) == 2))

[1] 524
```

Close enough?, as the sample prob was `c(0.7, 0.2)`. It is suggested to make use of `makeClass`, rather than `makePatch`, so we'll try that, in the context of your while. We'll perhaps need some empty vals, initialized outside the `while` loop, then some changes in notation:

```
patches <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 18L)
for (i in 1:18) {
  patches[i] <- sample(1:10, 1)
}
```

```
> patches
 [1]  1  3  6  8  1  7  6  8  6 10  6 10  4  1  7  8  4  8
```

```
> sum(patches)
[1] 104 # so we'll get to 50
```

```
while ((freq(tst_ls, value = 3) < 50)) {
  tst_ls <- makeClass(
    context = tst_ls,
    npatch = max(which(cumsum(patches) < 50)), # matches while
    size = patches[1:npatch],
    bgr = 1,
    edge = FALSE,
    rast = TRUE,
    val = 3
  )
}
```

Leaving this here for some head scratching done in context of `< 50`.
#examining patches

```
> patches
 [1]  1  3  6  8  1  7  6  8  6 10  6 10  4  1  7  8  4  8
```

```
> cumsum(patches)
 [1]   1   4  10  18  19  26  32  40  46  56  62  72  76  77  84  92  96 104
```

The adjustment to `npatch`  and `size` brings it into conformity with `while`, and finally works as I think you wanted. Cool package.

Comment: `(length(tst_ls[tst_ls[] == 3]) < 50)`  should be `(freq(tst_ls, value=3) < 50)` (you should never use `[]` on a Raster object in production code.

Comment: I'm clearly still learning and propagating bad code, will fix, thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I cleaned up the formatting a bit - I hope it didn't change the meaning. But in future, it's best to use proper indentation, as it makes the code much easier to read and for others to learn from it.

Comment: Noted, and thanks for tidying. I'll do so going forward.